# Jackson can't construct Record without repeating @JsonProperty (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, java-record

I have the following immutable DTO:

```
@Builder
@With
public record MyDTO(
  String field1,
  String field2
) { }
```

Jackson can't construct this record object

```
...
InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.package.MyDTO`
(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
...
```

I am using Java 18, Spring Boot 2.6.7 and Jackson 2.13.3

The way I solved it is to instruct Jackson where to inject which JSON property:

```
@Builder
@With
public record MyDTO(

  @JsonProperty("field1")
  String field1,

  @JsonProperty("field2")
  String field2
) { }
```

This approach, however, does not scale and is error prone (repeating field definitions). Is it possible to make it work without `@JsonProperty`?

Comment: I think you can have a method annotated with `@JsonSerialize` instead of specifying each field. check it here https://dev.to/brunooliveira/practical-java-16-using-jackson-to-serialize-records-4og4

Comment: No, that didn't work. I found this article as well and interestingly, it says Jackson shouldn't have any issues with record serialization for Jackson > 2.12.3 (I use Jackson 2.13.3)

Comment: Is that @Builder from lombok?  Maybe need to add the @AllArgsConstructor?

Comment: @AndrewS Java 16 Records have a canonical (i.e. all-args) auto-generated constructor by the compiler.

Comment: That's a [documented issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-future-ideas/issues/46), and records should be [supported since release version 2.12.0](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/2709#issuecomment-736221708).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko nice! I would say it is a nice solution given the options. To use `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)`

Comment: I've tried to deserialize JSON into a record with `@Bilder`/`@With` and without `@JsonProperty` everything goes fine. Jackson 2.13.3, JDK 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records are supported by the Jackson version `2.12.x`. No need for `@JsonProperty` on every constructor argument.

The problem was that Spring was using a different, transitive, older Jackson version from another package.